# Too many argument

Tags: excel, excel-formula

My result intended involved a lot of function, statement, etc. And it is important for all formula to be in one cell.

But Excel responded by "too many argument for this function"

Is there limit for Excel?
Or is it just messy formula?

Hard to explain the problem, this best I can do.

```
   A      B         C             D
1 Num1  Num2      ITEM           [RESULT]
2 1032  27022601  QW&AP-XXXX    
3 1111  20486547  KLK-XXXXXXXX
```

The formula in D2 and D3

Intended result:

```
D2 = QW&AP-1032
D3 = KLK-20486547
```

Formula:

```
=IF(NOT(ISERROR(SEARCH("XXXXXXXX",D2))),SUBSTITUTE(D2,"XXXXXXXX",$B2),IF(NOT(ISERROR(SEARCH("XXXX",D2))),SUBSTITUTE(D2,"XXXX",$A2),IFERROR(IF(INDEX(INDIRECT(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE($C2,"&","_"),"-","_")," ",""),":","_")),COLUMNS($D$1:D$1))="","",INDEX(INDIRECT(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE($C2,"&","_"),"-","_")," ",""),":","_")),COLUMNS($D$1:D$1))),""),D2))
```

Comment: "too many argument for this function" means than YOU don't use the allowed number of arguments. That means messy formula...

Comment: It may be easier to explain what you are trying to do, what is the expected result in D2.  Also a formula cannot refer to itself.

Comment: The formula consist of two operation. The result of the first run is needed to run the second operation. Thats why i think it refer to itself

Comment: Your example shows two different outcomes, why does D2 take Num1 and D3 take Num2? How do you decide which is which?

Comment: By SEARCH length of X's (4 or 8)

Answer (score 1):

Messy formula

Your error is due to too many arguments being used for the first if formula. Unless it serves a purpose, remove the final `,D2` from the end of your formula.

To avoid this in the future, try to make note of where in the formula the indicator lands when you press OK on the error message. Another great tool in Excel is the Evaluate Formula button (under Formula -> Formula Auditing). It's worth learning to use it.

But be aware, the way you've shown the problem, you are creating circular references by referencing column D in a formula meant to be in column D...